# Select specific value for curl brace in f-string

Tags: python, string

I have the following f-string:

```
test = [51, 138]

for i in test:
    data = {
  'ajax': '{"tab_id":"t0","cur_page":1,"cur_trie":"distance","query":"","critere":{"id_marque":[f"{{str(i)}}"]},"sliders":{"prix":{"id":"#range_prix","face":"prix","max_counter":997748,"min":"1","max":"400000"},"km":{"id":"#range_km","face":"km","max_counter":1098088,"min":"1","max":"500000"},"millesime":{"id":"#range_millesime","face":"millesime","max_counter":1179169,"min":"1910","max":"2022"}},"req_num":2,"nb_results":"11964250","current_location_distance":-1,"logged_in":false}',
  'tabs': '["t0"]'
}
```

and I want to index the values as string from the list test in the list of values assigned to `critere`. However, I cannot properly index these values as the entire dictionary is a string, and there are multiple curly braces involved. How would I approach a situation like this?

The result I get it:

```
{'ajax': '{"tab_id":"t0","cur_page":1,"cur_trie":"distance","query":"","critere":{"id_marque":[f"{{str(i)}}"]},"sliders":{"prix":{"id":"#range_prix","face":"prix","max_counter":997748,"min":"1","max":"400000"},"km":{"id":"#range_km","face":"km","max_counter":1098088,"min":"1","max":"500000"},"millesime":{"id":"#range_millesime","face":"millesime","max_counter":1179169,"min":"1910","max":"2022"}},"req_num":2,"nb_results":"11964250","current_location_distance":-1,"logged_in":false}', 'tabs': '["t0"]'}
{'ajax': '{"tab_id":"t0","cur_page":1,"cur_trie":"distance","query":"","critere":{"id_marque":[f"{{str(i)}}"]},"sliders":{"prix":{"id":"#range_prix","face":"prix","max_counter":997748,"min":"1","max":"400000"},"km":{"id":"#range_km","face":"km","max_counter":1098088,"min":"1","max":"500000"},"millesime":{"id":"#range_millesime","face":"millesime","max_counter":1179169,"min":"1910","max":"2022"}},"req_num":2,"nb_results":"11964250","current_location_distance":-1,"logged_in":false}', 'tabs': '["t0"]'}
```

The expected output should be:

```
{'ajax': '{"tab_id":"t0","cur_page":1,"cur_trie":"distance","query":"","critere":{"id_marque":["51"]},"sliders":{"prix":{"id":"#range_prix","face":"prix","max_counter":997748,"min":"1","max":"400000"},"km":{"id":"#range_km","face":"km","max_counter":1098088,"min":"1","max":"500000"},"millesime":{"id":"#range_millesime","face":"millesime","max_counter":1179169,"min":"1910","max":"2022"}},"req_num":2,"nb_results":"11964250","current_location_distance":-1,"logged_in":false}', 'tabs': '["t0"]'}
{'ajax': '{"tab_id":"t0","cur_page":1,"cur_trie":"distance","query":"","critere":{"id_marque":["138"]},"sliders":{"prix":{"id":"#range_prix","face":"prix","max_counter":997748,"min":"1","max":"400000"},"km":{"id":"#range_km","face":"km","max_counter":1098088,"min":"1","max":"500000"},"millesime":{"id":"#range_millesime","face":"millesime","max_counter":1179169,"min":"1910","max":"2022"}},"req_num":2,"nb_results":"11964250","current_location_distance":-1,"logged_in":false}', 'tabs': '["t0"]'}
```

@Mozways answer is the solution I'm looking for; alternatively, here's the example requested in the comment:

```
#following with your example
test = [51, 138]
another_test = [5, 10]

data = []
for i, j in zip(test, another_test):
    data.append({
  'ajax': '{"tab_id":...,"critere":{"id_marque":[%s], "id_color":[????]},"sliders":...}' % i, # how to implement j here also for id_color
  'tabs': '["t0"]'
})
```

Comment: These names suggest your strings may be intended to be JSON. If so, a JSON parser would be the appropriate tool.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica It's the data required for a POST request. However, it doesn't seem to work if I remove the outer strings. So, I am in want of knowing, how to implement an f-string so it retains its formatting.

Comment: Are you trying to *produce* these strings? Then a JSON dumper would be the tool.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica How does that work exactly? I have used `json.dumps(data)`, however this add ```\\``` for every white-space, and converts the entire thing into a string. I return back to the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really wanted to use a f-string, the whole string should be `f'…'`. Adding `'f"xxx"'` in the middle of the string does not make it a f-string.

The issue here with f-strings is that it requires curly brackets, which would require you to heavily escape all the curly brackets of the JSON: something like `f'{{"critere":{{"id_marque":[{i}]}}}}`.

A simple way might be to use classical python string formatting: `"abc%sefg" % "c"`.

Also, you need to use a list to store your dictionary or you will overwrite the dictionary again and again with the last loop element:

```
test = [51, 138]

data = []
for i in test:
    data.append({
  'ajax': '{"tab_id":...,"critere":{"id_marque":[%s]},"sliders":...}' % i,
  'tabs': '["t0"]'
})
```

output:

```
[{'ajax': '{"tab_id":...,"critere":{"id_marque":[51]},"sliders":...}',
  'tabs': '["t0"]'},
 {'ajax': '{"tab_id":...,"critere":{"id_marque":[138]},"sliders":...}',
  'tabs': '["t0"]'}]
```

###### several parameters:

```
test = [51, 138]
another_test = [5, 10]

data = []
for params in zip(test, another_test): # params should be in order
    data.append({
  'ajax': '{"tab_id":...,"critere":{"id_marque":[%s], "id_color":["%s"]},"sliders":...}' % params,
  'tabs': '["t0"]'
})
```

output:

```
[{'ajax': '{"tab_id":...,"critere":{"id_marque":[51], "id_color":["5"]},"sliders":...}',
  'tabs': '["t0"]'},
 {'ajax': '{"tab_id":...,"critere":{"id_marque":[138], "id_color":["10"]},"sliders":...}',
  'tabs': '["t0"]'}]
```

*NB. if you need a more complex format, or variable order of the parameters, then a f-string with quoting is more appropriate*

Comment: Any issue with the answer?

Comment: On another note, if I used the `zip()` function in the loop and had multiple loop variables such as ```i, j```, how would I implement `j` into this as well as ``i``?

Comment: You should maybe provide an example ;)

Comment: That works also! I managed to figure it out also with ```% (i, j)``` but yours is much cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

This would yield a list of the two dictionaries with the requested values:

```
test = [51, 138]
data = list(
  {'ajax': '{{"tab_id":"t0","cur_page":1,"cur_trie":"distance","query":"","critere":{{"id_marque":["{0}"]}},"sliders":{{"prix":{{"id":"#range_prix","face":"prix","max_counter":997748,"min":"1","max":"400000"}},"km":{{"id":"#range_km","face":"km","max_counter":1098088,"min":"1","max":"500000"}},"millesime":{{"id":"#range_millesime","face":"millesime","max_counter":1179169,"min":"1910","max":"2022"}},"req_num":2,"nb_results":"11964250","current_location_distance":-1,"logged_in":false}}'.format(i),
  'tabs': '["t0"]'}
  for i in test)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary and then set the value directly and the use json.dumps to format result.

```
import json
test = [51, 138]
ajax = {
  "tab_id": "t0",
  "cur_page": 1,
  "cur_trie": "distance",
  "query": "",
  "critere": {
    "id_marque": [
      None
    ]
  },
  "sliders": {
    "prix": {
      "id": "#range_prix",
      "face": "prix",
      "max_counter": 997748,
      "min": "1",
      "max": "400000"
    },
    "km": {
      "id": "#range_km",
      "face": "km",
      "max_counter": 1098088,
      "min": "1",
      "max": "500000"
    },
    "millesime": {
      "id": "#range_millesime",
      "face": "millesime",
      "max_counter": 1179169,
      "min": "1910",
      "max": "2022"
    }
  },
  "req_num": 2,
  "nb_results": "11964250",
  "current_location_distance": -1,
  "logged_in": False
}
for i in test:
    ajax["critere"]["id_marque"] = [i]
    data = {
    'ajax':  json.dumps(ajax),
    'tabs': '["t0"]'
    }
    print(data)
```